# Debian 8.5: Lampp Doesn't Start

Tags: debian, lampp

I'm using Debian 8.5 Jessie and I installed lampp.7.0.9. But when i want to start lampp like this:

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

then i'm taking a fail like this:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.0.9-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
httpd: Syntax error on line 136 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load
modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /opt/lampp/modules/mod_ssl.so: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
XAMPP:  Another FTP daemon is already running.
```

What should i do for starting lampp? Please help me!

Comment: Wrong place for a question like this. Try SuperUSer or AskUbuntu.. However I will add that the issue is clearly stated in the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the same issue after installing xampp and running apache server, Here is the solution.

```
Please open your Linux terminal and follow given Steps.

1: $ cd /opt/lampp/etc

2: $ sudo gedit httpd.conf

Now comment line# 136 Like this (put # sign before it)

#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem on fresh **Xubuntu 16** installation, and resolved by commenting a line in the apache configuration file

here is the command i used:

```
$ sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```

**then inside the file comment line 136**

save it and everything will go fine

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message as mentioned by the comment above.

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 136 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load
modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /opt/lampp/modules/mod_ssl.so: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

See here on how to install. https://serverfault.com/questions/446328/aws-installing-mod-ssl-on-apache

FYI always google your error messages before posting on SO!